# C - warning: control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: c, compiler-errors

So, I'm doing this simple example of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define NUM_TRABALHADORAS 3

pthread_t tid[NUM_TRABALHADORAS];

void* printsomething(void *arg){
    printf("Entrei\n");
}

int main (void) {
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_TRABALHADORAS; i++){
        pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &printsomething, NULL);
    }
}
```

I compile with:

```
gcc -Wall -pthread  inicio.c
```

And receive this warning:

```
inicio.c: In function ‘printsomething’:
inicio.c:12:2: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: `void *` means your function is returning a pointer. Yet it isn't

Comment: Add `return NULL;` after your `printf()`.

Comment: Note that there's a good chance your main thread will terminate and the program will end before any of your created threads get the opportunity to run. You probably want to investigate `pthread_join()` to make sure they're able to finish.

Answer (score 2):

The function `printsomething` is supposed to return a `void` pointer but it is returning nothing. Have the function return `NULL`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define NUM_TRABALHADORAS 3

pthread_t tid[NUM_TRABALHADORAS];

void * printsomething(void * args){
    printf("Entrei\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main (void) {
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_TRABALHADORAS; i++){
        pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &printsomething, NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP would be passing the wrong type of function to `pthread_create()` if they did this.

Comment: Oh oops, I didn't realize `pthread_create()` required a `void *` return type. I'll fix it.